# Python парсинг с помощью selenium+PhantomJS

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

имеется около 8к ID. 
как задачу вижу я: захожу на сайт-> переключаю фрейм->нахожу поле ввода->вставляю ID -> жму поиск -> открывается новая страница (в новом окне, это важно!) -> жду пока загрузится -> переключаюсь -> сохраняю текущий адрес -> закрываю страницу -> переключаюсь на предыдущую -> переключаю фрейм -> очищаю поле ввода -> вставляю след ID

Вопросы:
Как WebDriverWait дождаться загрузки страницы в новом окне?

```
driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_SearchButton').click()
# driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    time.sleep(1)
    for handle in driver.window_handles:
        if handle != current_window:
            driver.switch_to_window(handle) #Вот здесь открывается новое окно
```

Перед циклом новое окно еще не открылось и мы не знаем все открытые driver.window_handles, решил только через time.sleep(). Но есть же решение "из коробки" ?

Comment: Не факт, что _весь_ ваш код имеет непосредственное отношение к проблеме. Попробуйте изолировать проблемный кусок, чтобы другим пользователям было легче разобраться в проблеме.

Comment: Чтобы ваш вопрос мог бы быть более полезным для других посетителей, старайтесь одной проблемой ограничиваться. К примеру, создайте минимальным, но самодостаточный пример кода, который работает с webdriver.Chrome, но перестаёт работать с PhantomJS (headless). [mcve]

Comment: @jfs, да, понял, спасибо. оставил только один вопрос, каким все-таки ожиданием можно дождаться загрузки страницы, открывающейся в новом окне?

Comment: [пример кода с WebDriverWait (2012)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9191759/4279).